# upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04.5 on travelmate

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, kernel

I wanted to upgrade my travelmate b115-m/roxy.
After the upgrade the display was dark, nothing to see.
Hard reset, then I received a display with the message kernel panic.
I tried to start it with recover, the same result.
Then with an other kernel - 3.13.0.43 - also in recovery, the same error.
I can boot with a live ubuntu from the usb stick, but is the version 12.02.
I can see the file system, but I dont know, what to do?
Please help me..

I need help really! Nobody can help...!

[display1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfpNP.jpg)
[with kernel 3.13.0.43](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK1p7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Backup (if you have not already).
2. 16.04 fresh install.
3. run your configure script (or if you don't know how to make one then follow written instructions from a text file)

Each of those things has many stack exchange answers. The reason you should take these steps is that systems accumulate issues over time and it's generally less work to just start fresh than fix them, and secondly if you ever have a hard drive fail or otherwise lose a system having a backup of your data and s script for your applications and customizations will save you a lot of stress.

As an alternative there is a recover system option in the live OS.

Comment: Thank you! To make a backup is ok, but some files are not readable...How can I change it?

Comment: thank you, meanwhile I did it, I change the permission with chmod a+r.

Comment: b.t.w. when I do a new fresh install, can I reserve my old  data?